# A tool to “display arrows” in a model in geometric network,

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, geometric-network

I am trying to find a tool to “display arrows” in a ModelBuilder model in geometric network.

I couldn’t figure out if there is a tool that can be added to the model to display the arrows as we do with the tool available in the “utility network analyst” bar

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The [Utility Network Editing](http://solutions.arcgis.com/utilities/water/help/network-editing/) toolbar has a button that will toggle flow arrows.

You'll see this if you download the solution (it comes with sample water data):
[image]